# Pivot Table shows #NUM! error for standard deviation population

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to understand why for certain categories there are #NUM! errors showing up in my pivot table. It doesn't make sense to me, because when I use standard  =stdev.p formula I'm getting value of 0%, which is correct. It's also inconsistent in treating other fields that are no different, but somehow are able to show the value correctly.

[image: pivot_table_error]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.